# How to make the output order random in process synchronization, semaphore?

Tags: c, synchronization, semaphore

```
int main() {
    sem_t * sem;

    sem = sem_open("share", O_CREAT, 0 ,1);
    sem_unlink("share");

    int i;
    if (fork()) {      
        for (i=0;i<10;i++) {
            sem_wait(sem);
            display("Hello world\n");
            sem_post(sem);
        }
        wait(NULL);
    } else {
        for (i=0;i<10;i++) {
            sem_wait(sem);
            display("Bonjour monde\n");
            sem_post(sem);
        }

    }   
    return 0; 
}
```

I am trying synchronization between process, it works perfectly but the child process starts logging the Bonjour monde text after the parent finishes(after 10 Hello worlds). Can the outputs order be random like

```
Hello World
Bonjour monde
Bonjour monde
Hello World
....
```

Instead of 10 Hello Worlds and then 10 Bonjour mondes.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for *lack* of synchronization.  Do you need the semaphore at all?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have stronger expectations of "random" output than the term means on its face.  Your original code is indeed non-deterministic (*i.e.* random) with respect to the order of outputs.  That might be clearer over a longer run.  It happens to disfavor switching from one output to the other, so the output clumps, but that does not make it non-random.

Since you are dissatisfied with deterministic alternation, too, I suppose you mean something along the lines of there being for each line an equal chance of each output, uncorrelated with the previous line.  In that case, you need, ironically, to exert some control.  For example, you could adapt @CraigEstey's two-semaphore solution so that instead of each process deterministically posting to the other's semaphore, each randomly chooses which semaphore to post to, by means of a pseudorandom number generator such as `rand()`.  I leave the details as an exercise.

Answer (score -1):

You have a race condition.

When the main process does `sem_post`, it loops [quickly] and [almost] immediately does the *next* `sem_wait` and acquires the semaphore before the child process has a chance to get it.

The simple/naive solution is to add a small `usleep` at the bottom of each loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

int
main()
{
    sem_t *sem;

    setlinebuf(stdout);

    sem = sem_open("share", O_CREAT, 0, 1);
    sem_unlink("share");

    int i;

    if (fork()) {
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            sem_wait(sem);
            printf("Hello world\n");
            sem_post(sem);
            usleep(10);
        }
        wait(NULL);
    }
    else {
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            sem_wait(sem);
            printf("Bonjour monde\n");
            sem_post(sem);
            usleep(10);
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

The output is now:

```
Hello world
Bonjour monde
Hello world
Bonjour monde
Hello world
Bonjour monde
Hello world
Bonjour monde
Hello world
Bonjour monde
Hello world
Bonjour monde
Hello world
Bonjour monde
Hello world
Bonjour monde
Hello world
Bonjour monde
Hello world
Bonjour monde
```

---

**UPDATE:**

As mentioned below, a *two* semaphore solution is better as it guarantees the alternation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

int
main()
{
    sem_t *sempar;
    sem_t *semcld;

    setlinebuf(stdout);

    sem_unlink("parent");
    sempar = sem_open("parent", O_CREAT, 0, 1);

    // by blocking child semaphore, this guarantees parent starts first
    sem_unlink("child");
    semcld = sem_open("child", O_CREAT, 0, 0);

    int i;

    if (fork()) {
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            sem_wait(sempar);
            printf("Hello world (%d)\n",i);
            sem_post(semcld);
        }
        wait(NULL);
    }

    else {
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            sem_wait(semcld);
            printf("Bonjour monde (%d)\n",i);
            sem_post(sempar);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE #2:**

> But the output is not random it prints HelloWorld and then Bonjour and repeat.

Okay, then the single semaphore solution is the better one, with some modifications:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

sem_t *sem;

void
doloop(time_t seed,const char *msg)
{
    int i;
    int rval;

    srand(seed);

    for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        rval = rand() % 100000;
        sem_wait(sem);
        printf("%s i=%d rval=%d\n",msg,i,rval);
        sem_post(sem);
        usleep(rval);
    }
}

int
main()
{
    time_t seed;

    setlinebuf(stdout);

    sem_unlink("share");
    sem = sem_open("share", O_CREAT, 0, 1);

    seed = time(NULL);

    if (fork()) {
        doloop(seed,"Hello World");
        wait(NULL);
    }

    else {
        doloop(seed ^ ~0,"Bonjour monde");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: adding delay is not answer in my humble opion, here we can't guarantee schedule sequence because every iteration sem_post() is called, if we want execute child or parent loop one after the other we have to do sem_post() after the loop completes, as other will not get chance until one does sem_post()

Comment: NMDV, but sleeping is pretty much never the right solution to synchronization problems.  It would be better, IMO, to use two semaphores to achieve process alternation without any sleeping.

Comment: @ShivYaragatti This is not a reason to downvote. Downvotes are reserved for _egregiously_ wrong answers [per SO guidelines]. A comment is better because it gives the responder a chance to improve their answer. And, your analysis is incorrect as the solution _does_ work, and I've answered similar/identical questions before _without_ ever getting DVed. Doing what you suggest will _not_ work. Did you even try it? And, if I were you, I'd refrain from DVing until you get some more experience with SO.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes, two semaphores would be better, and I was going to code one and add it, to show a progression. That's why I said "simple/naive"

Comment: @CraigEstey thanks educating i accept my mistake, sorry for DVing, tried but i couldn't reverse it, not sure it possible for you do it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I've added a two semaphore solution

Comment: Thank you @CraigEstey. But the output is not random it prints HelloWorld and then Bonjour and repeat.

Answer (score -1):

as you are doing `sem_post()` in every iteration, it will wakeup all the process waiting for sem in every iteration, we can't guarntee same process will getback it after `sem_post()` so

that happening mostly because of the scheduling behavior of your machine.
your code produces following output in my linux machine

`Hello world
Bonjour monde
Bonjour monde
Bonjour monde
Bonjour monde
Bonjour monde
Bonjour monde
Bonjour monde
Bonjour monde
Bonjour monde
Hello world
Hello world
Hello world
Hello world
Bonjour monde
Hello world
Hello world
Hello world
Hello world
Hello world`

actually to guanrantte to get 10 "hello" message after  10 "Bonjor" messages then we have to try calling  `sem_wait() sem_post()`  before and after completing `for()` in child and parent, and also we can't guarntee which one will be schedule first(either parent or child can run first) i.e

```
if (fork()) {
    sem_wait(sem);
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        display("Hello world\n");
    }
    sem_post(sem);
    wait(NULL);
}
```

Comment: This seems to miss the point of the question.  The OP wants to *avoid* the situation your code produces, with one process producing all its output before the other.  He wants the outputs mixed (better).

Comment: @JohnBollinger, OP is asking why it is not happening randomly, it is happening randomly but in that run mostly it is not, output will be depends on how the process scheduling happens in this case.  you can check OP code different machine you can't guarntee that sequence or instead of 10  if you change it to 100 iterations you can see the randomness if run few times, it all depends on scheduling behavior. but if you modify code as in my answer you can guarantee the sequence. that is my point.

Comment: Yes, the OP mistakes the behavior he observes as deterministic, when it is not.  But that does not change the fact that he wants a more even distribution of the outputs from his two processes, and your suggestion produces the exact opposite.